# Why insgesamt and not imgesamt?

Tags: etymology

Someone learning German asked me, and I was embarrassed not to be able to explain.

[The Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/insgesamt) says

> Bedeutung
> im Ganzen, alles in allem, alles zusammen[genommen], zusammen

> BEISPIELE.
> es waren insgesamt fünfzig.
> ein insgesamt positiver Eindruck.
> trotz einiger Rückschläge sind wir insgesamt ein gutes Stück weitergekommen

Why does it involve accusative, and not dative?

Comment: Don't be embarrassed for not being able to explain the etymology of old German words!  :-)  This one isn't even in Pfeifer's etymologischem Wörterbuch (https://www.dwds.de/d/wb-etymwb). I can't answer this, but it's clear that the language was different when these words originated. Compare "trotzdem" or "insgeheim". In a few decades, people won't understand the origin of "deswegen" any more.

Comment: What does the case have to do here? This isn't a noun or a pronoun.

Comment: It seems to be a compund noun ... or at least a noun which is made of compund parts. I want to think "in dem gesamten", and not "in das gesamte".

Comment: Grimm kennt *insammt* und *ingesammt* [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/insammt#GI00541). Da *zusammen* als feste Wendung steht und /ins/ von *inz-* nicht zu unterscheiden ist (ebenso *jetzt, jez*, (älter) *je zu*, usw.) wäre das ein plausibler Ansatz. Englisch *inasmuch* neben Deutsch *insoweit* lässt weitere Vermischung erahnen. Also alles in allem erschwert das vermutlich die Suche nach dem wahren Grund. Übrigens ist der Unterschied zwischen Akkusativ und Dativ (und Lokativ) schon äußerst früh aufgemischt worden. So regiert *wegen* Dativ, vgl. *von wegen*, aber *wegen dir* acc. "für dich".

Comment: s. a. Französisch *en gros*, Englisch *in total*

Answer (score 1):

A view back in history enlights us. It derives from "insgesammt"<sup>[(1)](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB#3)</sup> which you can understand as "in das Gesamte (genommen/vereint)". This construct means something like "taken/united as in its entirety". This way you can recognize it needs accusativ since "das Gesamt" (entirety) is the object which is built up as result of "take (as)/unite (to)", and that's why it is not related to "im" which is a shortened "in dem" (dative).

Comment: @vectory: Deine 2 Alternativformen implizieren dasselbe, stehen also nicht im Widerspruch. Gäbe es im Deutschen eine Dativform, wäre das "imgesamten" (= 'im Gesamten'), d.h. man hätte zwangsweise die Endung "en". Über deine Beleidigung kann ich nur müde lächeln.

Comment: Donnerwetter. Dativ vs Akkusativ unterscheidet soweit nicht über die en-Endung, die für dein Beispiel an den Haaren herbeigezogen worden sein muss. Wo und wann die Endung ausgelass worden wäre, ist mit *einem* einzigen Blick in die Geschichte leider überhaupt nicht zu klären. Topkek ist übrigens nicht als Verleumdung zu verstehen.

Comment: Siehe dazu etwa niederländisch *En tenslotte* ("und zum Schluss", "schlussendlich", "um zu schließen"). So wäre ferner, so wie dann eine ursprüngliche e-Endung *Gesamt-e* nachweisbar wäre, welche ich bezweifelt habe, auch auf adverbiale Anwendung zu prüfen, um niederdeutschen Einfluss adequat auszuschließen.